# Horizantal Gridview item overflow item in android

Tags: android, gridview

Hello everyone I use to Horizantal Gridview like Gallery . I adding gridview item dynamically but last item overlap some image . For example I ' adding 12 images. The gridview display only 8 item , other images under to last item  .  here is my xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zzbothtime.MainActivity" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frmlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_gridtableLayout"
            android:layout_width="1050dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:columnWidth="80dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:gravity="center"                    
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"

                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"                   
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
                 >
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
    android:onClick="btnAddOnClick"
    android:text="Ekle" />
```

Comment: why dont you try recycler view?

Comment: I developping eclipse

Comment: Use Android Studio.....Gradle makes your job a lot easier...